# Content with width: fit-content is getting wrapped when using position: absolute and left: 50% in windows but not wrapping in mac

Tags: css, windows, macos

The below code makes the content wrap or makes the div occupy only 50% of the browser's width in windows(thus making the content in to wrap if the content width is more than 50% of the browser width). But it's not happening in mac, it is trying to occupy 100% of the browser's width and wraps if the content width is more than 100% of the browser's width. Why does this difference occur?
see the demo in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sevenu/egtvc95j/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  background-color:#E7E9EB;
}
#myDIV {
  height:300px;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
.bluediv {
  background-color:lightblue;
  width: fit-content;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The width: fit-content position: absolute and left 50%<</h1>

<div id="myDIV">
    <div class="bluediv">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Est quidem eius et nihil modi et omnis commodi et error galisum?
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the use of `left: 50%`.

Try like below:

```css
body {
  background-color: #E7E9EB;
}

#myDIV {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.bluediv {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: fit-content;
  position: absolute;
  inset: auto 0; /* left and right = 0*/
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>The width: fit-content position: absolute and left 50%</h1>

<div id="myDIV">
  <div class="bluediv">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Est quidem eius et nihil modi et omnis commodi et error galisum?
  </div>
</div>
```